# Using a VS2010 Database Project for only specific schemas in another database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project

thanks for reading...

Here's my problem:

**The Background**: I have been tasked with being a Build Manager (first time doing so). Among other things, this includes creating scripts to update the staging DB. I would like to utilize a Database Project for this so I may keep it in source control and also have it apart of TFS Labels to create a snapshot of the DB at the time of the build. *This seems pretty straight forward to me.*

**The Setup**: In our dev environment, we have a copy of our production DB. This DB is the one where our new data base objects will be deployed when we go live. We also have a copy of it in staging for testing.

**The Goal**: The only schemas (and related objects) I need in the Database Projects are limited only to the ones that aren't in production.

**The Problem**: When I create a new Database Project, I have no option to select only certain schemas to import (that I am aware of). Is there a way to **only** import Schemas A, B, and D and leave out dbo and C? Along with this, is it possible when using the 'Schema Comparison' to compare only selected schemas within the database?

Please let me know if my question and information are incomplete.

Thanks.

-Justin

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio do you have?  (Professional/Premium/Ultimate)

Comment: Have you tried creating a special account with limited permissions to attempt to hide objects you don't want to sync?

Comment: I've not tried that. However, I did try to simply delete the extra schemas I didn't need from the DB Proj. The problem with that is when I tried to build the script, VS threw errors about not being able to resolve dependencies (expected, I suppose). I assume if I tried your idea, the same would happen.

Comment: You won't be able to build without the dependent objects.  Why exactly do you want to hide these schemas?

Comment: Don't want to capture things that are already in production. Its a way we are trying to version the DB, but only the objects that are created for the app. The goal is to make it easier when deploying to the production database. There's no need to worry about a script overwriting something that already exists. Just want the app specific DBOs to be added. Does this make sense? Am I way off base here?

Comment: The database deployment in Visual Studio does a really good job of preventing overwriting.  You are supposed to keep your entire DB in the project, and then when you want to deploy you point it at production and tell it to deploy.  If you are uncomfortable with that, most should be, then you can just tell it to just make the script only when deploying.  Then you can review the script to make sure it isn't dropping anything it shouldn't.

Comment: I see what you are saying; makes sense. While this doesn't meet the need of what we are looking for (versioning only the app specific items through a DB project), you've confirmed that we need to reexamine our end goal for this.Thanks, Carter.